# max-width marked as invalid property value

Tags: html, css

I have a simple div with inline style having `max-width:100%;` . The doctype is `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` but Chrome console marks it as invalid property value (Chrome  version:67.0.3396.99). You may inspect the following snippet output:

```html
<div id="signupDiv" style="width:300px;max-width:l00%;margin:auto">
Inspect the problem here
</div>
```

Comment: There is a typo there it should be 100% not l00% its typed as lower l and not number 1

Comment: @AjajRajguru is right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code

```
<div id="signupDiv" style="width:300px;max-width:l00%;margin:auto">
Inspect the problem here
</div>
```

Updated code

```
<div id="signupDiv" style="width:300px;max-width:100%;margin:auto">
Inspect the problem here
</div>
```

Typo issue with 100%

Comment: LOL! I have no idea how L was typed instead of 1 ! Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Everything is fine just typo error was there

```
<div id="signupDiv" style="width:300px;max-width:100%;margin:auto">
```

Inspect the problem here